# How is Dell bloatware reinstalling itself on my computer despite removing it?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, security, windows-update, privacy

I'm working with a bunch of Dell wireless keyboards and mice. There's nothing fancy or special about them.  They're not even Bluetooth. They're just the ordinary, cheapie stock keyboards and mice that come with new Dell computers.

When you plug in the USB wireless receiver, a program called "Dell Peripheral Manager" automatically downloads and installs itself as part of the "driver" package. Not only is it useless, it also displays this gigantic data privacy notice on the screen:

[image: Dell Crapware]

I already hate useless crapware, but I absolutely loathe crapware that wants to collect personal data... from a KEYBOARD of all things (can we say keylogger, perhaps?).  So I uninstalled it.  But this program is like a cockroach that refuses to die.  If another user signs in, it comes back.  If I unplug the USB nub and plug it back in, it comes back.  If I run Windows Updates, it comes back.  Like a virus, it won't go away.

I have tried everything I know to prevent this $@#%*ing driver from resurrecting itself without success.  This stupid software has now become my white whale!  Here's the procedure I used that *should* have killed it off for good, but didn't:

- I unplugged the computer from Ethernet (to make sure it could not contact Microsoft for updates).
- I plugged in an old wired USB Apple keyboard (it works without a driver and Apple doesn't allow Microsoft to distribute its Boot Camp drivers through Windows Update).
- I wiped the hard drive and reloaded a fresh, clean copy of Windows 10 (to make sure there was no Dell factory software on it).
- Since this is Win10 Pro, I used Group Policy to disable driver downloads via Windows Update ("Do not download drivers with Windows updates" and "Prevent device metadata retrieval from the Internet" policies).
- Gave it a reboot for good measure and plugged it back into Ethernet.
- Ran Windows Update to bring everything current with patches.  Group Policy is working because device installation settings are grayed out and Windows did not install missing drivers when I ran updates.

[image: Device Installation Settings]

- Plugged the Dell wireless keyboard receiver back into the system.

FAIL!!!  The driver came back!!!  I got that stupid data consent notice again, despite this being a totally fresh, clean install of Windows 10.

At this point, it's not about the driver anymore (I could still use Group Policy to forbid this one, specific driver from loading -- maybe). I'm a very privacy-conscious person and I want to know how this 3rd-party software is winding up on the computer without my consent and despite all my efforts to block it.

Comment: After `Dell Peripheral Manager` is downloaded through Windows Update.  What updates appear in your Windows Update History?  This information is necessary to indicate which update to block.  It's possible the device has a hidden storage device, it's not common for a keyboard or mouse to have storage, but it's feasible that by plugging in the receiver you are automatically running Dell software (i.e. AutoPlay).

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/community/Virus-Spyware/Setting-up-new-XPS-15-remove-bloatware/td-p/5005975 and https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9300-bloatware/td-p/7581806 for similar issues. One suggestion was to turn off Windows update of third-party drivers to prevent reinstallation.